# How to access map data in modal button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
upgrademodalPlan(el){
    let data = {
     subscription_plan_id: el.subscription_plan_id,
     recurrence_time: el.payment_frequency,


    }

}
```

Here I can able to access the `el` but in model button how to access this el

```
{ el.is_subscribed ? <button element={el} className="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-t-20"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upgradePlan" onClick= 
 {this.upgrademodalPlan.bind(this, el)}>Upgrade Plan</button> : null }


   makePayment(el){
     the same data what i was accessing in upgrademodalPlan should be accessed here, but i cannot able to access
   }

   <div id="upgradePlan" className="modal fade emp-add-list" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style={{display: "none"}}>
                 <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                       <div className="modal-header">
                          <h6 className="modal-title">Upgrade Plan</h6>
                          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                       </div>
                       <div className="modal-body">
                          <div className="form-group row  m-b-0">
                             <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div className="">
                                      <div className="row">
                                         <div className="col-md-12">
                                            <form>
                                            <div className="form-group">


                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">

                                              <div className="checkbox">

                                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.makePayment.bind(this, this.props)}>Make Payment</button>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </form>
                                         </div>

                                      </div>

                                   </div>

                             </div>

                          </div>

                       </div>
                    </div>

                 </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: can any one let me know

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question, but if you want pass el in model button you can use props maybe

```
{ el.is_subscribed ? <button element={el} className="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-t-20"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upgradePlan" onClick= 
 {this.upgrademodalPlan.bind(this, el)}>Upgrade Plan</button> : null }
```

Comment: From this button i am opening modal in that modal i am having button on click on that button i need to access modal button el

Comment: Maybe you can create a component modal and pass el in props. I hope this way help you

Comment: May i know how i cal as i am passing el how can i take from props